# Loading strategy in Ebean

Tags: playframework, ebean

I have a model entity with a list of objects:

```
@ManyToMany
public List<SomeObject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

When I have fetched such an entity (e.g. `find.byId(id)`) are there all the fields completly loaded already or is there a lazy loading? What about this list of objects with a many to many relation?

Or more general, can I configure this in ebeans? What is the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in Ebean you don't have to initialize this relation with empty list. You can write simply:

```
public List<SomeObject> listOfObjects;
```

and code will work as before.

And the answer to your question:

Yes, by default many-to-many relation is lazily loaded. So when you call `find.byId(id)` then simple select will be executed. And when you try to use this collection (for example calling `listOfObjects.size()`) then additional select will be called.
To see how it works you can turn on SQL logging.